# Git commit removed a file but I don't understand how

Tags: git, msysgit

A file disappeared from Git repository, but there's no commit that removes it. I noticed it only because the project couldn't compile.
I tried to bisect to the first bad commit - i.e. the first commit when this file disappeared, but the commit history has nothing to do with this file, there's nothing in diff that removes it. 
I am using Win7 machine and MSysGit to work with Git(GitHub).
I have no idea how it happened, and I want to understand what caused it. Any suggestions on how to investigate it are welcome!

Comment: Is the file known to git? E.g. can it be found on gitHub somewhere in history?

Comment: Yes. I can find it in the history.

Answer (score 2):

Most likely the file was never added to the git repository.  Unfortunately, this is a relatively common error; you create a file but never add it to git.  Since git knows nothing about it, it cannot help you recover the file.  To avoid this problem, run git status often and let git tell you about files that exist in your working directory that it does not know about.  Also, clone the repo and make sure the build succeeds in the clone.

Comment: No it was in the history. I can find it in the previous commits.

Comment: What do you mean by "there's nothing in diff that removes it"?  What do you get from 'git show A' where A is the sha of the first commit in which the file does not appear?

Comment: Some patch that has nothing that removes the file

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar case once. It turned out that the file (or in my case, a change to that file) disappeared as part of a merge commit due to incorrect conflict resolution. Assume the following:

- Your "master" branch has a file A.
- A "devel" branch based on "master" modifies file A and adds file B.
- On "master", A is also modified.
- Merging "devel" to "master" creates a conflict in file A.

If you now resolve the conflict in A but also unstage the non-conflicting B from the merge commit, B "disappeares" and is not in "master" although Git will tell you that "devel" is fully merged into "master". Moreover, there is no indication in the log / gitk that B got removed as part of the merge commit.

Comment: What happened is that I had file A - that was in the history of master. Then there was some pull->merge->commit->push by someone else. And the file disappeared. It's still in the history, but not in HEAD. Nothing in the log. I suspect that something went wrong in merge, but again there's nothing in the commit log that relates to the file.

Answer (score 0):

This happens on windows when the case (lower/upper) is changed in a file name for example by deleting and then recreating it with the new case.

When you pull this change, the deletion will make git delete the "wrong" file, since windows doesn't differentiate between case.

Solution, if you didn't change the file: use git reset -- filename and git checkout -- filename